# For a Paypal IPN what's the difference between auth_amount and mc_gross?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm having a hard time finding this out from the documentation.  I have some code I've inherited which needs to get he payment amount from a Paypal IPN transaction.  It's expecting the variable "auth_amount" from a Paypal IPN but is not getting passed this field.  It looks to me from the Paypal docs as though I should be using the field "mc_gross" which is labelled as "Full amount of the customer's payment, before transaction fee is subtracted.".

The Paypal IPN docs describe the "auth_amount" field as "Authorization amount", which doesn't mean much to me.

I'm going to change it to use mc_gross, but I just want to check first that I'm not missing something silly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this out:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables

> mc_gross 
>   Full amount of the customer's
>   payment, before transaction fee is
>   subtracted. Equivalent to
>   payment_gross for USD payments. If
>   this amount is negative, it signifies
>   a refund or reversal, and either of
>   those payment statuses can be for the
>   full or partial amount of the original
>   transaction.

Comment: Hi, yes, I saw that, I'm just trying to understand what auth_amount is and why this code may use it.  Do you know what auth_amount does?

Comment: Auth ammount is how much the user authorised to send you before fees and stuff.